# Tkinter canvas not updating in an infinite loop

Tags: python, animation, canvas, tkinter

I created some code to show 2 balls moving, but when I run it, it doesn't show the movement of the balls.Furthermore it stops running and ignores the infinite loop This is my code up to now:

```
import tkinter as tk

class ObjectHolder:
    def __init__(self, pos, velocity, radius, id):
        self.id = id                # the id of the canvas shape
        self.pos = pos              # the position of the object
        self.r = radius             # the radius of incluence of the object
        self.velocity = velocity    # the velocity of the object

    def moveobject(object):
        x = object.pos[0] + object.velocity[0]  # moves the object where
        y = object.pos[1] + object.velocity[1]  # 0=x and 1=y
        object.pos = (x, y)
        canvas.move(object, x, y)

class App():
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.objects = []
        for i in range(0, 2):
            position = ((i+1)*100, (i+1)*100)
            velocity = (-(i+1)*10, -(i+1)*10)
            radius = (i + 1) * 20

            x1 = position[0]-radius
            y1 = position[1]-radius
            x2 = position[0]+radius
            y2 = position[1]+radius

            id = canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2)
            self.objects.append(ObjectHolder(position, velocity, radius, id))
        self.symulation(self.objects)

    def symulation(self, objects):
        for object in objects:             # this moves each object
            ObjectHolder.moveobject(object)

        # This part doesn't work. It is supposed to update the canvas
        # and repeat forever.
        self.canvas.update()
        root.update()
        self.canvas.after(50, self.symulation, objects)

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=600, bg="light blue")
canvas.pack()
App(canvas)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code. One big one was the way you were updating the position of the existing canvas objects. The `move()` method needs to know the amount of movement (change in x and y value), not the new absolute position.

When I fixed that it turned out that the velocities were too big, so I reduced them to only be 10% of the values you had.

Another problem was with the way the `ObjectHolder` class was implemented. For one thing, the `moveobject()` method had no `self` argument, which it should have been using instead of having an `object` argument. You should probably also rename the method simply `move()`.

The code below runs and does animate the movement.

```
import tkinter as tk


class ObjectHolder:
    def __init__(self, pos, velocity, radius, id):
        self.id = id                # the id of the canvas shape
        self.pos = pos              # the position of the object
        self.r = radius             # the radius of incluence of the object
        self.velocity = velocity    # the velocity of the object

    def moveobject(self):
        x, y = self.pos
        dx, dy = self.velocity
        self.pos = (x + dx, y + dy)
        canvas.move(self.id, dx, dy)  # Amount of movement, not new position.


class App():
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.objects = []
        for i in range(0, 2):
            position = ((i+1)*100, (i+1)*100)
#            velocity = (-(i+1)*10, -(i+1)*10)
            velocity = (-(i+1), -(i+1))  # Much slower speed...
            radius = (i + 1) * 20

            x1 = position[0]-radius
            y1 = position[1]-radius
            x2 = position[0]+radius
            y2 = position[1]+radius

            id = canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2)
            self.objects.append(ObjectHolder(position, velocity, radius, id))

        self.simulation(self.objects)

    def simulation(self, objects):
        for object in objects:             # this moves each object
            object.moveobject()

        # This part doesn't work. It is supposed to update the canvas
        # and repeat forever.
#        self.canvas.update()  # Not needed.
#        root.update()  # Not needed.
        self.canvas.after(50, self.simulation, objects)

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=600, bg="light blue")
canvas.pack()
app = App(canvas)
root.mainloop()  # Added.
```